# A singular $2×2$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

We assume a singular $2×2$ matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{pmatrix}.$ Then $ad=bc$ and $A^2=(a+d)A$ and $A^n=(a+d)^{n-1}A.$ So

$$B=\sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac {A^{2n}}{(2n)!} = I+ \sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac {(a+d)^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}A$$

By the ratio test, the series $\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac {(a+d)^{2n-1}}{(2n)!}$ converges and we have:

$$\sum_{n = 1}^{+\infty} \frac {(a+d)^{2n-1}}{(2n)!} = \frac{\cosh (a+d) -1}{a+d}$$

Could $B$ be a zero matrix?

Comment: I don't think this will be true in general. Even if you take a special case when A is nilpotent matrix, then B will be a non-singular matrix. So you have a counter-example.

Answer (score 1):

$B=0\implies 0=\det A=(\frac {a+d}{1-\cosh (a+d)})^2\implies a+d=0$, a contradiction.